# Capybara unable to find font awesome icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, font-awesome

This is a feature spec that I am trying to run.
It seems that font awesome icons are ignored by Capybara...
In my index the admin is able to delete any videos by clicking on the trash-icon.
Help would be very appreciated

**the index I am testing**

```
    <%= link_to video_path(video), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}  do %>
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt trash"></i>
   <% end %>
```

**Rspec** test is red

```
scenario "delete a video" do
  video_1 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWYKTiqPvYA&tg")
  video_2 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxIPVAPRBi4")

 visit videos_path

 first(:link, '.i.fas.fa-trash-alt.trash').click

 expect(page).to have_content("Video was successfully destroyed")
end
```

If I add the text *delete* between the `i` tags:  `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt trash">delete</i>`

**Rspec** test is green

```
scenario "delete a video" do
  video_1 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWYKTiqPvYA&t")
  video_2 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxIPVAPRBi4")

 visit videos_path

 first(:link, 'delete').click

 expect(page).to have_content("Video was successfully destroyed")
end
```

I 've used `save_and_open_page` and Icons don't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:
I added a class in my link_to

```
<%= link_to video_path(video), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "delete_link"  do %>
  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt trash"></i>
<% end %>
```

And this way it's green:

```
scenario "delete a video" do
    video_1 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yozj4ZB98Gg")
    video_2 =  Video.create(url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxIPVAPRBi4")

    visit videos_path

    first(:css, ".delete_link").click

    expect(page).to have_content("Video was successfully destroyed")
end
```